# Powershell Script to store and move clusters

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, hyper-v

I am trying to create a powershell script to perform some Hyper-V Cluster Groups migrations.

My script basically gets the server hosts into the Cluster Groups and store their names into a variable.

At this moment I have successfully managed to do it when the cluster have only two physical servers, but I cannot do it when it has more than two.

See my script below:

```
### Get all cluster nodes in an array ###
Write-Host 'The possible servers to host the Quorum disk are:'
$AllNodes = Get-ClusterNode #| Select Name
Write-host $AllNodes

Write-Host ''

### Get current cluster owner ###
$ClusterOwner = Get-ClusterGroup -Name "Cluster Group" | Select-Object -expand OwnerNode
Write-Host 'The current owner of Cluster Group is:' $ClusterOwner

### Determine inactive node as a string ###
$InactiveNode = ($AllNodes -notmatch $ClusterOwner) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

Write-Host ''

### Get User input to confirm or cancel the Quorum move ###
$confirmation = Read-Host "Confirm moving Quorum disk to" $InactiveNode". Please confirm with Y/N"

if ($confirmation -eq 'y'){
    Write-host ''   
    Write-host 'Moving Quorum disk...'
    Move-ClusterGroup "Cluster Group" -Node $InactiveNode
} else{
    Write-host ''   
    Write-host 'Quorum move cancelled!'
```

As you can see in the code above, I am storing all nodes into $AllNodes variable and I compare the inactive one in the end to determine which one I should be prompting.

This script will works for when I have only 2 servers not for more, as it will be storing multiple names into the variable.

Is there a way to store each host in a different variable?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that this is not all the code in question.

There is little reason to store in separate variables, no would recommend that.

As long as you collect all node names as a array, then loop to process them, you should be fine. As of what you posted, I don't see any code that performs iteration of the nodes collected / stored in the variable..

```
 $AllNodes = 'node01','node02','node03'

"There are $($AllNodes.Count) in the list to process"

ForEach ($NodeName in $AllNodes)
{
    "Processing node named $NodeName"
}

There are 3 in the list to process

Processing node named node01
Processing node named node02
Processing node named node03
```

Also, the is little reason to use Write-Host for what you are doing. Writing to the screen is the default. Just use the variable name of the quoted string without it. It's the same thing.

Depending on what PoSH version your are own, using Write-Host clear the buffer, meaning, there is nothing for you to use on the pipeline.

Comment: I will post the full code so you can see what I am trying to do, and post another comment here

Comment: I've posted the full code in the original question. as you can see I am prompting to the user to confirm to which Cluster Node he would like to be moving the disk.
That's why I would like to have it in different variables so I could prompt to the user the options and just take his choice, like 1 for xxx or 2 for xxx. Doing so I can minimise the errors.